# How can I manually generate a tz3 wallet address?

Tags: wallets, address

I want to be able to test some signing functionality (or lack thereof) with tz3 addresses, but I'm not sure how to create one.

Any advice on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tezos-client`?

```
tezos-client gen keys tzthree --sig p256
```

(then `tezos-client show address tzthree -S`)

Comment: Thanks will check it out!

Comment: Can confirm, that this worked perfectly, thank you.